# Android UI Testing launch Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I've been trying to write a simple UI Test for a Login Dialog in my Android App, but I've come to have trouble even starting the Login Fragment. I've tried several methods starting with ActivityTestRule to declare the Activity the Fragment depends on to launching my fragment isolated, but nothing seems to work.
This is the error I'm getting, from which I'm not able to draw any conclusions about what's going wrong:

```
E/TestRunner: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve activity for: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=de.smartwireless.smartconnect.debug/androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario$EmptyFragmentActivity (has extras) }
```

This is the initial code of my Testclass. It's not really populated because I want to make sure that the fragment launches correctly before I go on with the UI Testing itself:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class LoginTest {

    private lateinit var scenario: FragmentScenario<LoginFragment>

    @Before
    fun prepareLogin() {
        IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(SemaphoreIdlingResource.semaphoreIdlingResource)
        scenario = launchFragmentInContainer<LoginFragment>()
        scenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
    }

    @Test
    fun loginSuccess() {}

    @After
    fun finish() {
        IdlingRegistry.getInstance().unregister(SemaphoreIdlingResource.semaphoreIdlingResource)
    }
}
```

Comment: That indicates the activity the test framework uses to host the fragment is not found. What does your gradle file look like?

Comment: @dominicoder It's a really big project with a lot in the gradle file. What exactly would you be looking for in that? There's some confidential code in there that I'd like not to share on here.

Comment: Well that missing class is defined in `androidx.fragment:fragment-testing` so confirming that that exists, what version, and that you added it with `androidTest`, for starters.

Comment: I've got "androidTestImplementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.1.0-beta01")" in my gradle file. @dominicoder